How to add an event handler for component emit
How can I add an event handler to tie into a Vue Component's emit?
I have a top-level NoteSection component that contains a list of NoteItem components. The note items can emit events that will trigger an async loading process and display a spinner. The emit to handle this bubbles all the way up to NoteSection component and provides a callback to "completeProcessing" and stop the load state of the child components.
It is desired to have a parent "controller" component for NoteSection that will house API calls and invoke the above callback to stop loading state of the child NoteItem components.
Using Storybook, how can I create an event handler to tie into the NoteSection's "voidNote" emit? Essentially, I want to do a "setTimeout" and invoke the callback to simulate an async process.
NoteSection Story:
import type { Meta, StoryObj } from '@storybook/vue3'
import { note_mock_data } from './notes'
import NoteSection from '@/components/sections/notes/NoteSection.vue'

// More on how to set up stories at: https://storybook.js.org/docs/vue/writing-stories/introduction
const meta = {
  title: 'Sections/Notes',
  component: NoteSection,
  // This component will have an automatically generated docsPage entry: https://storybook.js.org/docs/vue/writing-docs/autodocs
  tags: ['autodocs'],
  argTypes: {},
  args: {
    // voidNote: (noteId: number, completeProcessing: () => void) => {
    //   console.log(`voiding note ${noteId}`)
    //   setTimeout(() => completeProcessing(), 2000)
    // },
    notes: note_mock_data,
    isLoading: false,
    isSuccess: true
  } // default value
} satisfies Meta<typeof NoteSection>

export default meta
type Story = StoryObj<typeof meta>
/*
 * Render functions are a framework specific feature to allow you control on how the component renders.
 * See https://storybook.js.org/docs/vue/api/csf
 * to learn how to use render functions.
 */
export const Primary: Story = {
  args: {}
}

export const NoteOwner: Story = {
  args: { isLoading: false, isSuccess: true, currentUserId: 1 }
}

export const Loading: Story = {
  args: { isLoading: true }
}

export const NoNotes: Story = {
  args: { isLoading: false, isSuccess: true, notes: [] }
}

export const LoadFailure: Story = {
  args: { isLoading: false, isSuccess: false }
}


NoteSection.vue Component:
<template>
  <div class="notes notes-tab-body">
    <LoadState :isLoading="isLoading" :isSuccess="isSuccess">
      <NoteList
        @editNote="$emit('editNote')"
        @voidNote="onVoidNote"
        :notes="notes"
        :currentUserId="currentUserId"
      />
    </LoadState>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'
import LoadState from '@/components/LoadState.vue'
import NoteList from './NoteList.vue'
import { type Note } from '@/models/notes/Notes'

const props = defineProps<{
  notes: Array<Note>
  currentUserId?: number
  isLoading: boolean
  isSuccess: boolean
}>()

const emits = defineEmits<{
  /**
   * Emits Edit Note event
   * @param {number} noteId - ID of the note that triggered the emit
   */
  (e: 'editNote'): void
  /**
   * Emits Void Note event
   * @param {number} noteId - ID of the note that triggered the emit
   * @param {callback} completeProcessing - Stops stop loading state for the item
   */
  (e: 'voidNote', noteId: number, completeProcessing: () => void): void
}>()

const isLoading = ref(props.isLoading)
const isSuccess = ref(props.isSuccess)

const onVoidNote = (noteId: number, completeProcessing: () => void) => {
  emits('voidNote', noteId, completeProcessing)
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.notes {
  > :first-child {
    margin: 0 0 1.5rem 0;
  }
}
</style>


I've tried the commented, voidNote in the args block but I receive the following ->
Object literal may only specify known properties, but 'voidNote' does not exist in type 'Partial<ComponentPropsAndSlots<DefineComponent<__VLS_TypePropsToOption<{ notes: Note[]; currentUserId?: number | undefined; isLoading: boolean; isSuccess: boolean; }>, {}, unknown, {}, {}, ComponentOptionsMixin, ... 6 more ..., {}>>>'. Did you mean to write 'onVoidNote'?

An even simpler solution is, as you tried, to declare your event handler into the args property of the meta variable, but by naming it onVoidNote.
The error message you got suggested you this renaming by the way, by asking you "Did you mean to write 'onVoidNote'?" ;-)
I did not succeed to find where the magic is performed, but it seems that using the event name prefixed with "on" is the convention to provide an event handler to a Vue component in Storybook. The documentation is unfortunately not really clear about that point.
In conclusion, the solution consists in prefixing your event handler with "on" in the args property. So instead of voidNote, you must use onVoidNote:
export const Primary: Story = {
  args: {
    onVoidNote: (noteId: number, completeProcessing: () => void) => {
      // Simulate async API call
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(`Note ${noteId} voided`);
        completeProcessing();
      }, 2000);
    }
  }
}

(The example reuses your Primary story, but you can also fix your event handler where it was initially.)

The simplest approach would be to adjust the template of the story to actually add a parent component to your tested component.
export const Primary: StoryObj<typeof NoteSection> = {
  render: (args) => ({
    methods: {yourEventHandler: () => {}},
    components: {NoteSection},
    setup() { return {args}; },
    template: '<note-section @voidNote="yourEventHandler" />'
  })
}

